# Large SQLIite Tables and Memory Use

Tags: sqlite, delphi, large-data

System:

- Windows 10 pro
- Delphi Alexandria (11) Pro
- SQLite (local access only)

I have a FireDAC TfdTable on a data module that accesses a large table (about 750 MB). When I do Table.Open while watching the Task Manager memory report, it looks like the entire table is being loaded into memory instead of a small subset (usage goes from about 24 MB to 1.1 GB).

Referring to the Delphi docs about Live Data, I have the Fetch options set per the recommendations and have a unique key on the table, though its name is not "PRIMARY" but it is the selected index when opening the table.

Fetch Options:

- Cursor Kind: ckAutomatic
- LiveWindowFastFirst: True
- LiveWindowParanoic: True
- Mode: On Demand
- Record Count Mode: cmTotal
- Recs Max/Min: -1
- Rowset Size: 25
- Unidirectional: False

Am I wrong to expect otherwise? If not, any suggestions on how to reduce memory use?

Thanks
Brian

Comment: Check if the table can be split into several sections or new tables.

An intelligent access to only needed data in the all in one table.    
In the past, this was always done with dbase due to the lack of memory.

Comment: I'm working on splitting the table into two and will rely on a master-details connect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a primary key to your table and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks. The table does have a unique primary key and it is set to use that index when it is opened. The Fates must be against me. I'll explore some more.

Comment: I had same problem and after a lot of struggling with it,  by adding primary key to table the problem solved.

Comment: Exactly! I split each of two main tables into two tables and created master-detail connections as needed. The MOST important thing was to have a primary key on all four tables, not just the main master table. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @BrianD.Warner,If solved your problem don't forget to accept my answer.